# How to set sitepages as blog post list default pages(Newpost.aspx,EditPost.aspx,Post.aspx)?

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-masterpage, blog, sitepages

We need to set our custom master page for blog site without applying to system master page(Settings Page), We tried by edit the existing blog pages using designer to change masterUrl - default.master to Custom.master. But it throws native hr error. So We Planned to create custom page(site page) and set it to blog post list default pages(Newpost.aspx,EditPost,Post.aspx). Please Suggest me an idea to achieve this?